# Typsescript: JSON conversion - convert simple JSON into more detailed format

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I am using typescript file where I am receiving a JSON response from an external api. Here I need to convert received JSON into another JSON format. Can anyone please help in conversion of JSON format?

Received from API:

```
type here
Employees: [
    { empid : 12345 },
    { empName: "John Doe" },
    { gender: "Male" },
    { hobbie: "Book" },
    { empid : 12347 },
    { gender: "Male" },
    { hobbie: "Gym" },
    { empid : 12346 },
    { empName: "Jill Doe" },
    { gender: "Female" },
    { hobbie: "Sport" },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

And need to convert into below:

```
type here
finalEmployee: [
    {
       empName : "John Doe",
       empDetails: [
        {
          serialNo : 1, 
          empid: 12345,
          gender : "Male",
          hobbie : "Book"
        },
        {
          serialNo : 2, 
          empid: 12347,
          gender : "Male",
          hobbie : "Gym"
        }
     ]
    },
    {
       empName : "Jill Doe",
       empDetails: [
        {
          serialNo : 2,
          empid: 12346,
          gender : "Female",
          hobbie : "Sport"
        }
     ]
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I am not able to split into desired format

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wExv3W) is what you're looking for?  I guess it depends on what guarantees you have about the order of those single-property objects.  If that approach meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates a failed use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API response doesn't seem good. but if you still have to, you can do this

```js
const Employees = [
  { empid: 12345 },
  { empName: 'John Doe' },
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { hobbie: 'Book' },
  { empid: 12346 },
  { empName: 'Jill Doe' },
  { gender: 'Female' },
  { hobbie: 'Sport' },
]

function getFinalEmpItem(serialNo, { empName, empid, gender, hobbie }) {
  return {
    empName,
    empDetails: {
      serialNo,
      empid,
      gender,
      hobbie,
    },
  }
}

function convertFinalEmp(emp) {
  const final = emp
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
      const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(current)
      const lastObj = acc[acc.length - 1]

      if (key === 'empid') {
        acc.push({
          [key]: value,
        })
      } else {
        lastObj[key] = value
      }

      return acc
    }, [])
    .map((el, index) => getFinalEmpItem(index + 1, el))

  return final
}

console.log(convertFinalEmp(Employees))

/* Output
[
  {
    "empName": "John Doe",
    "empDetails": {
      "serialNo": 1,
      "empid": 12345,
      "gender": "Male",
      "hobbie": "Book"
    }
  },
  {
    "empName": "Jill Doe",
    "empDetails": {
      "serialNo": 2,
      "empid": 12346,
      "gender": "Female",
      "hobbie": "Sport"
    }
  }
]
*/
```

In the text, the type of empDetails tried to start with Array, so I inferred as follows.
If the empName is the same it into the details array in same Object.

```js
const Employees = [
  { empid: 12345 },
  { empName: 'John Doe' },
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { hobbie: 'Book' },
  { empid: 12346 },
  { empName: 'Jill Doe' },
  { gender: 'Female' },
  { hobbie: 'Sport' },
  { empid: 12346 },
  { empName: 'John Doe' },
  { gender: 'Female2' },
  { hobbie: 'Sport2' },
]

function getFinalEmpItem(serialNo, { empName, empid, gender, hobbie }) {
  return {
    empName,
    empDetails: {
      serialNo,
      empid,
      gender,
      hobbie,
    },
  }
}

function convertFinalEmp(emp) {
  const final = emp
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
      const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(current)
      const lastObj = acc[acc.length - 1]

      if (key === 'empid') {
        acc.push({
          [key]: value,
        })
      } else {
        lastObj[key] = value
      }

      return acc
    }, [])
    .map((el, index) => getFinalEmpItem(index + 1, el))
    .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const findObj = acc.find((el) => el.empName === cur.empName)

      if (!findObj) {
        acc.push({
          empName: cur.empName,
          empDetails: [cur.empDetails],
        })
      } else {
        findObj.empDetails.push(cur.empDetails)
      }

      return acc
    }, [])

  return final
}

console.log(convertFinalEmp(Employees))

/* Output
[
  {
    "empName": "John Doe",
    "empDetails": [
      {
        "serialNo": 1,
        "empid": 12345,
        "gender": "Male",
        "hobbie": "Book"
      },
      {
        "serialNo": 3,
        "empid": 12346,
        "gender": "Female2",
        "hobbie": "Sport2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "empName": "Jill Doe",
    "empDetails": [
      {
        "serialNo": 2,
        "empid": 12346,
        "gender": "Female",
        "hobbie": "Sport"
      }
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

It seems that there are items without empName in the added content.
So i fix it like this

```js
const Employees = [
  { empid: 12345 },
  { empName: 'John Doe' },
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { hobbie: 'Book' },
  { empid: 12347 },
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { hobbie: 'Gym' },
  { empid: 12346 },
  { empName: 'Jill Doe' },
  { gender: 'Female' },
  { hobbie: 'Sport' },
]

function getFinalEmpItem(serialNo, { empName, empid, gender, hobbie }) {
  return {
    empName,
    empDetails: {
      serialNo,
      empid,
      gender,
      hobbie,
    },
  }
}

function convertFinalEmp(emp) {
  const final = emp
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
      const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(current)
      const lastObj = acc[acc.length - 1]

      if (key === 'empid') {
        acc.push({
          [key]: value,
        })
      } else {
        lastObj[key] = value
      }

      return acc
    }, [])
    .map((el, index) => getFinalEmpItem(index + 1, el))
    .reduce((acc, cur) => {
      const lastObj = acc[acc.length - 1]

      if (!lastObj || cur.empName) {
        acc.push({
          empName: cur.empName,
          empDetails: [cur.empDetails],
        })
      } else {
        lastObj.empDetails.push(cur.empDetails)
      }

      return acc
    }, [])

  return final
}

console.log(convertFinalEmp(Employees))
/* Output
[
  {
    empName: 'John Doe',
    empDetails: [
      { serialNo: 1, empid: 12345, gender: 'Male', hobbie: 'Book' },
      { serialNo: 2, empid: 12347, gender: 'Male', hobbie: 'Gym' },
    ],
  },
  {
    empName: 'Jill Doe',
    empDetails: [
      { serialNo: 3, empid: 12346, gender: 'Female', hobbie: 'Sport' },
    ],
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: thanks,but I am sorry that I forgot add duplicated which need to be treated too.

Comment: @Sundaresan.C I think second one is you want

Comment: @Sundaresan.C It seems that there are items without empName in the added content. I'll edit and upload

Comment: ,but duplicate one will not have empname but will be in order of sequence to previous name. thats why I didn't mention emp name again after id :12347

Comment: so i added third one. check it please

Comment: if possible, can you pls help this one too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76235679/typescript-convert-complex-json-by-specfic-key-id