# Typescript: Convert complex json by specfic key ID

Tags: json, typescript

I have below json which has common key SubNo, PolicyNo and each may/may not have dynamic keys CanNo, RiNo, RenNo. These dynamic keys are in ordered , manner and

```
HealthPolicy: [
{ Subno: "12345" },         //1st group based on SubNo
{ PolicyNo: "78956Frtg" },
{ canNo: "78464" },
{ RenNo: "724643" },
{ RiNo : "84646" },
{ canNo: "8464646" },       // End of 1st group
{ Subno: "12344" },         // 2nd group
{ PolicyNo: "84567yuij" },
{ RenNo: "78784" },
{ RenNo : "879636" },
{ Subno: "12341" },     // 3rd group
{ PolicyNo: "34567drgu" },  
{ rftNo: "79784" },
.
.
.
```

]

I would like to split and group like below format based on PolicyNo (all the jobs in above json are in ordered format). here elements under PolicyNo & SubNo are so dynamic, we may have 5-10 dynamic elements or we may not even have those dynamic elements. But we have to group by PolicyNo which will always have SubNo as serial 1 like below:

```
finalHealth: [
{
   PolicyNo: "78956Frtg",
   details: [
    {
      serialNo : 1, 
      jobName: "SubNo",
      jobId: "12345",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 2, 
      jobName: "CanNo",
      jobId: "78464",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 3, 
      jobName: "RenNo",
      jobId: "724643",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 4, 
      jobName: "RiNo",
      jobId: "84646",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 5, 
      jobName: "canNo",
      jobId: "8464646",
    },
   ]
},
{
   PolicyNo: "84567yuij",
   details: [
    {
      serialNo : 1, 
      jobName: "SubNo",
      jobId: "12344",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 2, 
      jobName: "RenNo",
      jobId: "78784",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 3, 
      jobName: "RenNo",
      jobId: "879636",
    }
      ]
},
{
   PolicyNo: "34567drgu",
   details: [
    {
      serialNo : 1, 
      jobName: "SubNo",
      jobId: "12341",
    },
    {
      serialNo : 2, 
      jobName: "rftNo",
      jobId: "79784",
    },
   ]
},
.
.
.
]
```

Can anyone please help in converting ? I am not able to split into desired format.

[Some similar question but with static elements under common key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233036/typsescript-json-conversion-convert-simple-json-into-more-detailed-format)

Comment: How does this differ from your [very recent previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233036/typsescript-json-conversion-convert-simple-json-into-more-detailed-format)? I am strongly inclined to close this as a duplicate of that one unless you can [edit] here to clarify and explain the difference

Comment: @jcalz previous question has static elements, but here elements under PolicyNo & SubNo are so dynamic, we may have 5-10 dynamic elements or we may not even have those dynamic elements. But we have to group by PolicyNo which will always have SubNo as serial 1

Comment: Please [edit] to put that in the text of the question and make the differences clear. You should explicitly link to the other question also.

Comment: updated in question @jcalz , thanks

Comment: In the previous question you got a good example of how to write a loop to analyse the  JSON ( you can use `for`, `map`, `reduce`, etc). You can learn from that example and try to write your own solution that works for this problem. Or at least specify what is giving you trouble in writing that loop.

Comment: This question just isn't significantly different from the last one; you have to write some loops.  Maybe like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAxy4N) shows.

Comment: I think I already gave you the answer.

Comment: It’s not working in above case

Comment: Are you able to see [the suggestion in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAxy4N)?